# Remove character occurring after _ from all the files excluding file extension (.png)

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, sed

I was searching for a unix command/shell script to remove characters occurred after _ in all the files excluding file extension.

**Example:**

**b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop_6b5c74fa3d4b96f7557c3fd66f2555af.png**

should be renamed to

**b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop.png**

I have tried searching online and but was not able to find out a quick and optimal solution.

Please note that those extra characters are added randomly and varying in each file.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this using a **negated character class**:

```
f='b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop_6b5c74fa3d4b96f7557c3fd66f2555af.png'
sed 's/_[^_.]*//' <<< "$f"

b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop.png
```

`[^_.]` matches any character except DOT or underscore.

If you're using `bash` then you can do this in shell itself using:

```
echo "${f%_*}.png"
```

Comment: I thought OP wants to act on part after last underscore only.

Comment: Fair enough, i thought everything after the underscore, including more underscores. Although maybe it doesn't even matter if there's only one.

Comment: Actually, the OP doesn't say whether it should be after the first or after the last underscore, so either %% or % would be a solution.

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern:

```
(\_[\d\w]+)(?=(\.\w{2,3}))
```

to find every _akfgasfhsgfhha before .ext[ension]

Comment: Note that this only works with extensions with the length of exactly 3

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `cut` for the result like this:

```
file="b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop_6b5c74fa3d4b96f7557c3fd66f2555af.png"
new_file=$(echo $file | cut -d'_' -f1).$(echo $file | cut -d'.' -f2)
echo "New file name: ${new_file}"
```

Output:

```
New file name: b6d28-insurance-renewal-shop.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `f` holds the original filename,

```
 ${f%_*}.${f##*.}
```

would give you the transformed filename.